# Python pylint eclipse error

Tags: pylint

I had installed Pylint and also configured in Eclipse, but when i tried executing python program following error occures:

> PyLint: Executing command line: D:\dist\pylint-1.4.4\setup.py
>   D:\Practice\sam.py PyLint: The stdout of the command line is:  PyLint:
>   The stderr of the command line is: invalid command name 
>   D:\dist\pylint-1.4.4\setup.py D:\Practice\sam.py

Comment: How did you try executing the program?

Comment: As soon as control passes to next line[by enter] or by normal execution. Is any other way of execution is available to use Pylint?

Comment: Actually Pylint have to execute whenever we save a python file.